# Are .obj file vertex numbers globally unique?

Tags: wavefront

In this [`.obj`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) file:

```
o sometriangle
v 1 0 0
v 0 1 0
v 0 0 1
f 1 2 3

o somesquare
v 5 0 0
v 5 5 0
v 0 5 0
v 0 0 0
f 1 2 3   # HERE
f 1 3 4   # AND HERE
```

Do the marked lines refer to the vertices within their containing object, or are vertex numbers global?

Comment: Note to self - this may affect [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/6d2fe7edd5b72554daa07215e6cf6663aaac66d8#diff-c95aa6af1ef517957bfbff6af39992f5R212)

Answer (score 1):

The [OBJ specification](http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec) states

> For all elements, reference numbers are used to identify geometric
>   vertices, texture vertices, vertex normals, and parameter space
>   vertices.
>
> Each of these types of vertices is numbered separately, starting with
>   1. This means that the first geometric vertex in the file is 1, the second is 2, and so on. The first texture vertex in the file is 1, the
>   second is 2, and so on. The numbering continues sequentially
>   throughout the entire file. Frequently, files have multiple lists of
>   vertex data. This numbering sequence continues even when vertex data
>   is separated by other data.

So this means that the vertices are indeed numbered globally, at least within the same file.